# Check whether a path exists on a remote host using paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, scp, paramiko

Paramiko's [SFTPClient](http://www.metasnark.com/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SFTP-class.html) apparently does not have an `exists` method. This is my current implementation:

```
def rexists(sftp, path):
    """os.path.exists for paramiko's SCP object
    """
    try:
        sftp.stat(path)
    except IOError, e:
        if 'No such file' in str(e):
            return False
        raise
    else:
        return True
```

Is there a better way to do this? Checking for substring in Exception messages is pretty ugly and can be unreliable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See the [`errno` module](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html#errno.ENOENT) for constants defining all those error codes.  Also, it's a bit clearer to use the `errno` attribute of the exception than the expansion of the `__init__` args, so I'd do this:

```
except IOError, e: # or "as" if you're using Python 3.0
  if e.errno == errno.ENOENT:
    ...
```

Comment: This is probably the right way to do because stat() on a non existing file on a SFTP server via Paramiko will raise this particular exception with the errno.ENOENT error code: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/paramiko/sftp_client.py#L722

Answer (score 10):

Paramiko literally raises `FileNotFoundError`

```
def sftp_exists(sftp, path):
    try:
        sftp.stat(path)
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return False
```

Comment: It's actually `FileNotFoundError` (from the builtin exception classes) ETA: queued an edit to this answer to change it

Answer (score 6):

There is no "exists" method defined for SFTP (not just paramiko), so your method is fine.

I think checking the errno is a little cleaner:

```
def rexists(sftp, path):
    """os.path.exists for paramiko's SCP object
    """
    try:
        sftp.stat(path)
    except IOError, e:
        if e[0] == 2:
            return False
        raise
    else:
        return True
```